# Bypass proxies with iframes or something

Tags: php, html, iframe, proxy, reverse-proxy

I had the Idea to create something that bypasses proxies. My idea was to use an iframe or something like that which shows the content from a site which is shown, when i call the site with my private server.

So i started creating an simple iframe:

```
<html>
<iframe src="https://google.de/" width="800" height="600" ></iframe>
</html>
```

(works for my domain but not with google for me)

But then i found out that the page which is called by the iframe is just being called by my computer and not my server.

How can i redirect the contents my server gets into an iframe or something else to show it on my pc?

Comment: Perhaps share what you're trying to achieve? Because while possible, it sounds rather silly... iframes have nothing to do with this, or anything in html for that matter. For something like this, you're better off setting up a proper reverse proxy like apache or nginx to handle it loaded with whole lot of rewrite rules. If you're doing it with PHP, you'll basically have to write an entire reverse proxy program and then start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use this as an "in browser" proxy:
https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app

Answer (score 0):

With your method, you are telling the client browser to load google.de inside the iframe, at it will loaded depending on which permissions are  defined in the page you are loading, of course, google will block this attempt in order to avoid security problems.

what you can do is a page in your web that uses [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) to load the external web and make a response as if the responses come from your server.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i want to do. But when i use this I only get some plain text or at googles site the old layout. How can i get the complete site with css an js also loaded?

Comment: That's more difficult, for example you can:  - Load the main web.
  - Get all the css and js links.
  - Download this links and add to the response.
  - Send the reponse.  As you can see is a little bit difficult, and not really efficient.

Comment: Did it helps you?

Comment: I came up with using php proxy, it does exactly what i wanted to do.

Comment: wow, long time ago :), maybe you can write an answer with the details to help others with the same problem.